# Not getting matches for analyzers using CharMappingFilter with Lucene 4.1

Tags: java, search, lucene

Just updating codebase from Lucene 3.6 to Lucene 4.1 and seems my tests that use NormalizeCharMap for replacing characters in the analyzers are not working.

Below Ive created a self-contained test case, this is the output when I run it

```
--term=and--
--term=gold--
--term=platinum--
name:"platinum and gold"
Size1
name:"platinum & gold"
Size0

java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :1
Actual   :0
 <Click to see difference>
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:93)
    at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:647)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:128)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:472)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:456)
    at org.musicbrainz.search.analysis.Lucene41CharFilterTest.
    testAmpersandSearching(Lucene41CharFilterTest.java:89)
```

As you can see the charfilter does seem to work because the the text 'platinum & gold' is converted to three terms 'platnum, and , gold'. In fact search is working for 'platimum and gold' but not working for the original "platinum & gold" even though both index and search using same analyzer

```
package org.musicbrainz.search.analysis;

import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenStream;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Tokenizer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.charfilter.MappingCharFilter;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.charfilter.NormalizeCharMap;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.LowerCaseFilter;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Field;
import org.apache.lucene.index.*;
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser;
import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher;
import org.apache.lucene.search.Query;
import org.apache.lucene.search.TopDocs;
import org.apache.lucene.store.RAMDirectory;
import org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRef;
import org.apache.lucene.util.Version;
import org.junit.Test;
import java.io.Reader;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class Lucene41CharFilterTest
{
    class SimpleAnalyzer extends Analyzer {

        protected NormalizeCharMap charConvertMap;

        protected void setCharConvertMap() {

            NormalizeCharMap.Builder builder = new NormalizeCharMap.Builder();
            builder.add("&","and");
            charConvertMap = builder.build();
        }

        public SimpleAnalyzer() {
            setCharConvertMap();
        }

        @Override
        protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName, 
                                                         Reader reader) {
            Tokenizer source = new MusicbrainzTokenizer(Version.LUCENE_41,

                    new MappingCharFilter(charConvertMap, reader));
            TokenStream filter = new LowerCaseFilter(Version.LUCENE_41,source);
            return new TokenStreamComponents(source, filter);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testAmpersandSearching() throws Exception {

        Analyzer analyzer = new SimpleAnalyzer();
        RAMDirectory dir = new RAMDirectory();
        IndexWriterConfig writerConfig = new
            IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_41,analyzer);
        IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(dir, writerConfig);
        {
            Document doc = new Document();
            doc.add(new Field("name", "platinum & gold", Field.Store.YES,
                  Field.Index.ANALYZED));
            writer.addDocument(doc);
        }
        writer.close();

        IndexReader ir = DirectoryReader.open(dir);
        Fields fields = MultiFields.getFields(ir);
        Terms terms = fields.terms("name");
        TermsEnum termsEnum = terms.iterator(null);
        BytesRef text;
        while((text = termsEnum.next()) != null) {
            System.out.println("--term=" + text.utf8ToString()+"--");
        }
        ir.close();

        IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(IndexReader.open(dir));
        {
            Query q = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_41, "name", analyzer)
                .parse("\"platinum and gold\"");
            System.out.println(q);
            TopDocs td = searcher.search(q, 10);
            System.out.println("Size"+td.scoreDocs.length);
            assertEquals(1, searcher.search(q, 10).totalHits);
        }

        searcher = new IndexSearcher(IndexReader.open(dir));
        {
            Query q = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_41, "name", analyzer)
                .parse("\"platinum & gold\"");
            System.out.println(q);
            TopDocs td = searcher.search(q, 10);
            System.out.println("Size"+td.scoreDocs.length);
            assertEquals(1, searcher.search(q, 10).totalHits);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue I had to override new initReader() method for it to be applied when analyzer used with QueryParser. Not sure if the filter needs to be constructed in createComponents() as well but tests working if I just add to initReader.

```
class SimpleAnalyzer extends Analyzer {

        protected NormalizeCharMap charConvertMap;

        protected void setCharConvertMap() {

            NormalizeCharMap.Builder builder = new NormalizeCharMap.Builder();
            builder.add("&","and");
            charConvertMap = builder.build();
        }

        public SimpleAnalyzer() {
            setCharConvertMap();
        }

        @Override
        protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
            Tokenizer source = new MusicbrainzTokenizer(Version.LUCENE_35,
                    reader);
            TokenStream filter = new LowerCaseFilter(Version.LUCENE_35,source);
            return new TokenStreamComponents(source, filter);
        }

        @Override
        protected Reader initReader(String fieldName,
                                    Reader reader)
        {
            return new MappingCharFilter(charConvertMap, reader);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure but I guess the QueryParser does more than just analyzing.. 'and' for example is a special keyword. You might just hit an interesting edge-case :)

There are also more QueryParser implementations in 4.1... See for example http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/flexible/standard/package-summary.html

Comment: Thx but I just trying to update from Lucene 3.6 to Lucene .4.1 without rewriting large parts of my code.